# Python - trying to get URL (href) from web scraping using Scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get the URL, or href, from a webpage using web scraping, specifically using Scrapy. However, it returns an empty list when I response.xpath('XPATH').extract() the href link. The HTML page structure is:
[image: inspecting the webpage for HTML structure]
The specific HTML element href I'm trying to get is: `<a href="#2020-38970" class="redNoticeItem__labelLink" data-singleurl="https://ws-public.interpol.int/notices/v1/red/2020-38970">MAGOMEDOVA<br>MADINA</a>`

The result of the xpath command is:
[image: xpath command result returns empty]

For context, I'm trying to get the information in each person's URL and extract it, but I'm unable to retrieve the href from the web page.

I copied the full xpath of the HTML element, and it's: /html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft9Ia.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft9Ia.png)/div[6]/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNDWE.png)/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNDWE.png)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNDWE.png)/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNDWE.png)/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNDWE.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft9Ia.png)/a.

But this still returns [] when I run response xpath command.

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Comment: with Google Chrome you could right click on a page to inspect and get by context menu xpath value for focused element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation I personally wouldn't use xpath. I wouldn't even use Scrapy. In this situation I believe the simplest solution would be to instead use BeautifulSoup and requests together.

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
url=YOUR_URL_HERE
soup=BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
links=soup.find_all('a')
urls=[x['href'] for x in links]
```

This code will give you the href of every link on the page in a list, and you can filter the list further by the class or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `response.xpath ("//a[@class='redNoticeItem__labelLink']").extract()`